# How to invoke a SOAP Web service using Gatling 2.2.0

Tags: soap, gatling

I am new to Gatling and Scala. How to invoke / test a java SOAP web service using Gatling 2.2.0 ? I had searched google and gatling documentation, but could not find any link for that

code:

```
    val httpProtocol = http
        .baseURL("http://PUNITP83267L:8081/WebServiceProject/services/MyService")
    val headers_0 = Map(
        "accept-encoding" -> "gzip, deflate",
        "Content-Type" -> "text/xml;charset=UTF-8",
        "SOAPAction" -> "",
        "Content-Length" -> "275",
        "Host" -> "PUNITP83267L:8081",
        "Connection" -> "alive",
        "accept-language" -> "en-US,en;q=0.8",
        "user-agent" -> "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/49.0.2623.112 Safari/537.36"
    )

    val scn = scenario("SOAPRecordedSimulation")
        .exec(http("simple Soap Request")
        .post("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\">
              <soapenv:Body><greetMeResponse xmlns=\"http://ws.star.fs.infosys.com\">
              <greetMeReturn>Hello uMESH</greetMeReturn></greetMeResponse>
              </soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>\"\r\n")
        .headers(headers_0))
    setUp(scn.inject(atOnceUsers(1))).protocols(httpProtocol)
}
```

Comment: Is there any recorder for SOAP service call ? using SOAP UI  ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Am not sure if there is a recorder available. But, you could make changes to your script as below:

```
class testSOAP extends Simulation {

val httpProtocol = http
            .baseURL("http://PUNITP83267L:8081/WebServiceProject/services/")

    val header = Map(
    "accept-encoding" -> "gzip, deflate", 
    "Content-Type" -> "text/xml;charset=UTF-8", 
    "SOAPAction" -> "", "Content-Length" -> "275", 
    "Host" -> "PUNITP83267L:8081", 
    "Connection" -> "alive", 
    "accept-language" -> "en-US,en;q=0.8", 
    "user-agent" -> "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/49.0.2623.112 Safari/537.36")

    val scn = scenario("SOAPRecordedSimulation")
            .exec(http("simple Soap Request")
            .post("MyService")
            .headers(header)
            .body(StringBody("""<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\"><soapenv:Body><greetMeResponse xmlns=\"http://ws.star.fs.infosys.com\"><greetMeReturn>Hello uMESH</greetMeReturn></greetMeResponse></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>\"\r\n""")))
        setUp(scn.inject(atOnceUsers(1))).protocols(httpProtocol)
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much Gold. Where is it mentioned in the documentation ? Since this is Java web service, so we added MyService in post and URL is changed ( removed MyService from the baseURL). What if it is a .NET web service ? or the service URL ends with ?WSDL

Comment: I have split MyService from base URL just as a coding standard. It has nothing to do with java or .NET. You could also say, `.post("http://PUNITP83267L:8081/WebServiceProject/services/MyService")`and get rid of httpProtocol.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the SAOP code have to be in a file, and the base url doesn't contain the url context. It's just the base url (localhost:7001). Put the url context in the post function.

Here is the code :

```
package my.package

import scala.concurrent.duration._

import io.gatling.core.Predef._
import io.gatling.http.Predef._
import io.gatling.jdbc.Predef._

class MyClass extends Simulation {

  val httpProtocol = http
    .baseURL("http://127.0.0.1:7001")
    .inferHtmlResources()
    .acceptEncodingHeader("gzip,deflate")
    .contentTypeHeader("text/xml;charset=UTF-8")
    .userAgentHeader("Apache-HttpClient/4.1.1 (java 1.5)")

  val headers_0 = Map("SOAPAction" -> """""""")

  val uri1 = "http://127.0.0.1:7001/my-project/my-service"

  val scn = scenario("ScenarioName")
    .exec(http("request_0")
      .post("/my-project/my-service")
      .headers(headers_0)
      .body(RawFileBody("MyService_0000_request.txt")))

  setUp(scn.inject(atOnceUsers(1))).protocols(httpProtocol)
}
```

"MyService_0000_request.txt" is a file in bodies folder and contains the soap request body.