# SOAP API request format in Gatling tool

Tags: scala, gatling

Can anyone please provide me the format for SOAP API request in gatling tool?
I am having service url in which 10 methods are there, for each method I have a xml format of request. Can anyone please provide me the scala class structure in which the above request will be triggered.

Comment: Have you tried the suggestion here: [How to invoke a SOAP Web service using Gatling 2.2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36620768/how-to-invoke-a-soap-web-service-using-gatling-2-2-0)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to invoke a SOAP Web service using Gatling 2.2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36620768/how-to-invoke-a-soap-web-service-using-gatling-2-2-0)